# Можно ли определить что элемент HTML страницы подвергался изменению со стороны JS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Можно ли определить что элемент HTML страницы подвергался изменению со стороны JS после загрузки страницы? Например что-то такое:

```
<body>
  <p>Привет</p>
  <script>
    $('p').css('color', 'red');
    var pChanges = немногоВолшебства('p');
    alert(pChanges.HasChangedColor);
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: кровавый патчинг jquery может помочь

Comment: @Grundy можно переопределить методы jQuery https://stackoverflow.com/a/10742069

Comment: @Alex78191, собственно это я и назвал кровавым патчингом :-)

Comment: Можно слушать обновления элементов https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9488653/jquery-how-to-listen-for-dom-changes

Comment: @Grundy элегантное решение

Answer (score 1):

Можно попробовать использовать DOM MutationObserver. Пример, данный код выводит в консоль, тип изменения произведенного над элементом для примера сделал смену класса, и изменение цвета текста через 2с:

```js
// выбираем элемент
var target = document.querySelector('#some-id');

// создаем экземпляр наблюдателя
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
    console.log(mutation.target);
    console.log("Тип: " + mutation.type);
    console.log("Что меняется: " + mutation.attributeName);

  });
});

// настраиваем наблюдатель
var config = {
  attributes: true,
  childList: true,
  characterData: true
}

// передаем элемент и настройки в наблюдатель
observer.observe(target, config);

// добавляем класс и меняем  цвет 
$("#some-id").addClass("test")
// меняем  цвет через 2 c
setTimeout(function() {
  $("#some-id").css("color","red")
},2000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="some-id">
  Что-то
</div>
```

Подробнее почитать можно [здесь](https://habrahabr.ru/post/202366/)

Comment: Добавь пример использования в ответ